# Choose php version on Ubuntu 14.04 (php vs php5)

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, ubuntu-14.04

Im trying to start some projects on Laravel and Symfony

The issue is the following

When I write on terminal this:

> php -v

I get this:

> PHP 5.6.11 (cli) (built: Jul 13 2015 09:19:13)
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

and when I write this:

> php5 -v

I get this:

> PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:17:32)
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>
> with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend
> Technologies

The thing is that I have a few modules in the php 5.6.11 version and all the modules that I have installed are in the 5.5.9 version. And for both frameworks I need the modules in the 5.5.9 version but they get the 5.6.11 version.

English isnt my native language, sorry if I made some mistakes writing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. Installed php version manager "phpbrew" and it allows you to have differents versions of php and it also allows you to manage extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance compiled one of those versions manually?

The best option to have all modules for PHP 5.6 is to follow the following guide:

http://www.dev-metal.com/install-setup-php-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

It uses some repositories from ondrej, which are repositories that maintain different PHP versions for the latest ubuntu releases.

Comment: I did this and it updated the php5 version. Now I have both (php and php5) at 5.6.11 version, but still not working. Thanks for answering quickly. Im pretty new at this.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you need php 5.5.9 with all modules. And you don't need PHP 5.6?

Comment: I need any 5.4+ version, with modules mbstring, mcrypt and openssl. When I do php -m it shows some modules and when I do php5 -m it shows the modules I need.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you could try the following:

```
apt-get install php5-mcrypt php5-mbstring php5-openssl
```

After that you can do the following command (as root):

```
rm -rf /usr/bin/php && ln -s /usr/bin/php5 /usr/bin/php
```

This should link the php command to your php5 command, and you'll have the necessary modules installed.

Comment: The first command shows "Cant locate php5-mbstring package" and "Can't locate php5-openssl package", and for the second command I have not /usr/bin/php folder. 
In addition, "sudo php -i | grep 'Configuration File'" returns 
"Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => (none)"

Comment: How did you originally install these PHP versions?

Comment: php5 was installed with "apt-get install php5", the php version wasnt installed by me.